# Play custom sound when storyboard button tapped

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I made custom buttons inside of a .storyboard that need to play a sound when tapped (not a soundboard, just play a custom audio file of a button press).
Is there a sound option in the storyboard editor that would enable this? If not, how else can this be achieved?

Answer (score 5):

The storyboard doesn't allow you to assign a 'audio' to a button. What you can do however is use the fairly simple [AVAudioPlayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html) in a function;

### Add Libraries

To use the AVAudioPlayer you will first need to add 2 libraries/frameworks to your project. These Frameworks contains the basecode for the actual player and allows us (the app writers) to use it.

Select your project in xCode and go to **Build Phases**. Select **Link Binary with Libraries**. Press the little **[+]**-icon and add the frameworks:

- AudioToolbox
- AVFoundation

### Frameworks

Now we have to tell our code we will actually be using these two frameworks. Open the .H file of your controller and, at the top, add:

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
```

### Event + Player

Bind one of the events of a UIButton (via the storyboard), eg Touch Up Inside, to a new IBAction function (eg playSound).

By binding the event, your telling your application that if the users presses a button -> run this function/code.

Now, within your newly created IBAction function (eg playSound) add some code to create a player with an MP3 and play it;

```
- (IBAction)playSound:(id)sender
{

   // Load in a audio file from your bundle (all the files you have added to your app)
   NSString *audioFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"filename" ofType:@"mp3"];

   // Convert string to NSURL
   NSURL *audioURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:audioFile];

   // Initialize a audio player with the URL (the mp3)
   AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:audioURL error:nil];

   // Start playing
   [player play];

}
```

I hope this will help you along in the right direction?

Check the [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html) of Apple for al the functions/methods the AVAudioPlayer has got besides "play" (eg buffering, pause etc)

Comment: I tried exactly this, but it didn't work, it didn't play any sound... The only difference was that I didn't use a mp3 file, but I used a wav file. Does this work with wav file?

Answer (score 2):

The above code worked when I set the volume using

[player setVolume:1.0];

It was not working till I did that.